# Webex IOS SDK initialize not return callback

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, webex

when starting SDK in Webex integration SDK I did not return a callback on the device but work fine simulation

```
 webex.initialize { result in
                    if result {
                        print("User is authorized")
                        self.webxIntegration()
                    } else {
                        authenticator.authorize(parentViewController: self) { result in
                        if result == .success {
                            print("Login successful")
                            self.webxIntegration()

                        } else {
                            print("Login failed")
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
```